# Custom bootstrapper executed from windows-service, can't find endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, console-application, http-proxy

We have a solution consisting of an windows-service and a console application which acts as a bootstrapper calling a WCF service for work items.

All of this works fine except for when the solution is run in the customers environment which is in a closed network behind a http-proxy for external access. Everything works as expected up to the point where the bootstrapper calls the WCF service, which after 24s exits with the following error:

*System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at https://www.MyDomian.com/MyService.svc etc...*

Now, here is the kicker. If i start the bootstrapper manually (double-click the exe) it connects to the WCF service without problems.

**Known facts**

- Proxy is opened for traffic on port 443 against, www.MyDomian.com
- We have admin rights on customer computer
- WCF service is hosted in Windows Azure
- Solution works on the normal web!
- WCF is configured to use https
- https://www.MyDomian.com/MyService.svc is accessible from both IE and Chrome on customer computer
- IE: Internet Options, is configured with http-proxy
- Bootstrapper uses channelFactory to connect to wcf service

**Code windows-service uses to start the bootstrapper:**

```cs
var p1 = new Process{StartInfo = { UseShellExecute = false, FileName = MyConsoleApplication.exe } };

p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

p1.Start();
```

**WCF configuration on host:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBinding"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="500000"
             maxBufferSize="500000"
             maxBufferPoolSize="500000"  
             receiveTimeout="00:02:00" 
             sendTimeout="00:02:00"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>

</bindings>
<services>
  <service
    name="MyService"
    behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="IMyService"
              bindingConfiguration="MyBinding"/>
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpsBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy15" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

**WCF configuration on client:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBinding" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             receiveTimeout="00:02:00" 
             sendTimeout="00:02:00"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"            
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"            
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint name="MyService"
            address="https://www.MyDomian.com/MyService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="IMyService"
            bindingConfiguration="MyBinding"/>
</client>
```

**Tried so far:**

- System.Net app config element, such as using proxy defined in Internet Options
- Multiple configuration variations to bindings. Not tried other bindings
- process.Verb = "runas"
- Fiddler2 and WireShark shows that no tunnel is made. (For when it connects shows HTTP tunnel on port 443)
- Checked for race conditions, but can't find any
- Correct app config is loaded
- Smash head against wall

**Update 1**

- Running the windows service under a windows user made the bootstrapper connect, but as this will be an installation for several hundred external customers, we won't have that luxury.
- I ran the service under NETWORK SERVICE and LOCAL SERVICE, but bootstrapper would just quit with exception. Exception indicating lack of priviliges (exceptions were thrown when constructor initialized variables).
- The http proxy we are behind uses a .pac file. Tried pointing to this with system.net -> defaultProxy, without luck.
- Trying a different approach now to force the bootstrapper use a specific proxy.

*Added this to WCF client config*

```
<system.net>
   <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
       <proxy 
          proxyaddress="http://proxy.customerDomain.com:8080/" 
          bypassonlocal="True" 
          scriptLocation="http://config.customerDomain.com/proxy.pac"/>
   </defaultProxy>
```

What have we missed and/or any suggestions to what can cause this?

Thanks

Comment: did you check the firewall settings on the customer environment?

Comment: I don't have access to the firewall, but wouldn't I get no connection at all if it was something with the firewall? On a side note, the people administrating the firewall say its ok on their end.

Comment: Have you looked into Windows Service Hardening (WSH).  It is possible to have the firewall open, but WSH blocking your windows service outgoing connection.

Comment: What user is the service running under? Does it have network access?  I.e. try running it under NETWORK SERVICE

Comment: Running the service under a windows user with admin rights worked, but its not an option for me as we won't have that luxury where this solution will run. Updated main post